# how to implement a stack with two numbers inside each cell

Tags: java, class, generics, queue, stack

given a class TwoNumbers :

`public class TwoNumbers{ private int num1, num2; public TwoNumbers (int num1, int num2){ this.num1 = num1; this.num2 = num2; } }`   
I want to create a function `public Stack<TwoNumbers> func(Stack<Integer> st);` that does this:
(input)st : [8,4,7,5,3,2]
(output)st_final: [num1=5 | num2=7 , num1=3 | num2=4 , num1=2 | num2=8 ]

i managed to do this so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
    st.push(8);
    st.push(4);
    st.push(7);
    st.push(5);
    st.push(3);
    st.push(2);
    func(st);

}
public static Stack<TwoNumbers> func(Stack<Integer> st){
    Stack<Integer> st_top = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<TwoNumbers> st_final = new Stack<TwoNumbers>();
    int i;
    System.out.println("input st:"+st);

    for(i=0;i<=st.size()/2;i++) 
        st_top.push(st.pop());
        
    
    
    System.out.println("st_top:"+st_top);
    System.out.println("st_bottom"+st);
   

    return st_final;
```

but i have no idea how to insert the values into the st_final Stack

final output :
(input)st : [8,4,7,5,3,2]
(output)st_final: [num1=5 | num2=7 , num1=3 | num2=4 , num1=2 | num2=8 ]

Comment: After your for loop, both `st` and `st_top` should have the same size. (Put in some code to check this just to be sure.) Then write a second for-loop that loops `st.size()` times. In that second for loop, pop `st` **and** `st_top`. Use the two integers you get from those two pops to create an instance of `Two Numbers`. Push that instance of `TwoNumbers` to `st_final`.

Comment: After splitting the stack into two equal parts (you should verify that the stack's size is even before doing so), you will need to create the number pairs and push them into the new stack. you can create the pairs using `new TwoNumbers(n1, n2)` and then add the pair into the new stack using the `push` function

Comment: @ThomasBehr `for(i=0;i<=st.size();i++) {
            new TwoNumbers(st_top.pop(),st.pop());
         st_final.push(TwoNumbers);
        }`
it gives a null value for the two numbers, am i missing something? @NadavBarghil

Comment: @CodingHell2312x While the statement `new TwoNumbers(st_top.pop(), st.pop());` creates and initializes a new instance of `TwoNumbers`, it does not magically assign the name `TwoNumbers` to that new instance. You need to declare a local variable that holds the new instance and then use that local variable's name to push the new instance into `st_final`. (There's other ways to solve this, but I think you should learn the local variable stuff first.)

Comment: @ThomasBehr got it to work, excuse my lack of knowledge, i'm still in the early steps of oop . thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using the class TwoNumbers and the Stack class.

```
import java.util.*;

class TwoNumbers{
   int first, second;
   TwoNumbers(int f, int s){ first=f; second=s;}
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<TwoNumbers> s = new Stack<>();
        s.push(new TwoNumbers(1, 10));
        s.push(new TwoNumbers(2, 20));
    
        while(!s.empty()){
           TwoNumbers p = s.pop();
           System.out.println(p.first + ":" + p.second);
        }
    }
}
```